# getClass method in java

Tags: java

How is it that the getClass method in Object class is capable of dynamically returning Class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't return the class *name* - it returns the `Class` representing that object's type. Each object "knows" what type it really is - that's how casts can work or fail depending on the execution-time type. `Object.getClass()` just retrieves the relevant information from the object.

If you have a class which only contains a single `int`, each object will still take up more than 4 bytes in memory: there's effectively an object "header" containing things like a reference to the object's actual type, information to do with the monitor associated with that object etc.

Comment: Class is also a generic type, so if I do `Blah blah = new Blah();``blah.getClass()` returns a `Class<Blah>` .

Answer (score 1):

And there's nothing dynamic about it. The class of the object can never change.