# What does getClass() return as reference?

Tags: java

I've searched in forum and I understand `getClass()` returns a reference
but that it is a special reference and that every call to `getClass` returns exactly same reference for a given class.  That means that we can use "==" instead of "equals" to compare them.

I want to know how this Special reference is created and returned every time and how it is same every time

Comment: see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812680/getclass-method-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Class` object for each class is a singleton.  That means it is written in such a way that only one `Class` object exists for each class.

Comment: i afraid this is not the answer i'm looking for. i'm not sure but i think it build in class loader , can you give me more detail ?

Comment: More detail on what, exactly?

Comment: how getClass work ! does it make a Memory space when we run the code for each class ?

Comment: A.R., this *IS* the answer you are looking for!  There is absolutely nothing special about the reference that is returned from `getClass`.  The reason that `==` works is because there is only one instance of any given class, in a given classloader.  Because there is only one instance, `getClass` always returns the exact same value for a given class so the values are always `==`

Answer (score 0):

1. getClass() method returns the runtime class of the object.
2. returned Class object is the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the represented class.

Comment: you mean when we run the code , getClass create a reference for our class and return that everytime we call getClass ?

Answer (score 0):

A.R., I suspect that you are confusing a `Class` object, with an *instance* of that class object.  They are not the same.

There is only one `Class` object for each Java type.  `getClass` returns a reference to that `Class` object.  Because there is only one such object all references to it are identical, and `==` works.  The class object is loaded, by the `ClassLoader` the first time it is used.  Nobody has to "create" references to it.  It is sitting there, in memory, and can be referenced.  As @JoeC pointed out, it is a singleton. Bam!

There may be many *instances* of a given class.  Each independent instance has its own state that is not shared with any other instance.  One of the things that each instance has, as part of its state, is a reference to its `Class`.  That reference, of course, is the same as the reference in every other instance of the class.  They are `==`!

**Edited to add**: It may be helpful to know that `Class` objects are, themselves, instances of the type `Class<?>`.  There may be many `String`s but there is only one instance of `Class<String>` and its type (Class) is `Class<?>`.